# Beginner Java: keyboard input in one class to define three variables needed in another class, separated by spaces only

Tags: java, class

Hi this is a beginner Java question about classes, it is for an assignment so I would just like a hint not the answer. I looked around for this answer in other forums but I didn't seem to find the answer, but I apologize if this has already been answered.

I have a class that has three inTime doubles defined in one class, and I need to write the doubles to the screen in another class. The doubles are taken in as input from the keyboard.

My problem is, I have each inTime separated into three different double methods that return them as a double. When I set the new doubles in the writing class, to end the input I have to press enter, but I NEED the inTime inputs to be separated and ended by spaces. The only way I know how to set the variables is like this:

```
public class Race{

private double timeOne = 0;
private double timeTwo = 0;
private double timeThree = 0;

public double timeOne(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    timeOne = keyboard.nextDouble();
    return timeOne;
}

public double timeTwo(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);        
    timeTwo = keyboard.nextDouble();
    return timeTwo;
}
public double timeThree(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);        
    timeThree = keyboard.nextDouble();
    return timeThree;
}
```

This is the writing class:

```
public class RaceReport {

public void writeReport(){
    Race race = new Race();

    System.out.println("Enter the race times (in seconds): ");

    double timeOne = race.timeOne();
    double timeTwo = race.timeTwo();
    double timeThree = race.timeThree();
```

Should this be broken into three methods like I have, or only one method? I have no idea how I could yield three variables from one void method, separate return methods were the only thing that made sense.

Here is what the screen should look like when the doubles are being entered:

Enter the race times (in seconds):
85.6 120.5 90.2

The spaces separated should be separating the entries

Comment: One - it's the same method each time.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include an example of the output that you want? I'm just a little confused by your question.

Comment: I think an input example is better here. I don't recall the op mentioning anything about outputs

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I edited my post so that it shows what the console should look like when you are entering the numbers. They should be separated by spaces and after the last entry you hit enter and the rest of the code runs. Right now, I can only enter it separated by pressing enter each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use three methods but it will have no significant difference than you using only a single method. The simpler your code the better, so my suggestion is to use just one method. It is possible to produce three variables from one method by the way using the if-then-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to write the same code more than once your wrong.  If you have to copy and paste the same code more than once your wrong.  Don't forget that java gives you all of the tools you need to maintain simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I need to make instance variables with "this." in front of the variables in the method that assigns the private variables in the first method. Then, I need to use getter methods to assign variables in the writer method using the race class.

```
public class Race{

private double timeOne;
private double timeTwo;
private double timeThree;

public void readIntimes(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    this.timeOne = keyboard.nextDouble();
    this.timeTwo = keyboard.nextDouble();
    this.timeThree = keyboard.nextDouble();
}

public double getTimeOne(){
    return timeOne;
}

public double getTimeTwo(){
    return timeTwo;
}
public double getTimeThree(){
    return timeThree;
}
```

Writer class:

```
public void writeReport(){
    Race race = new Race();     

    System.out.println("Enter the race times (in seconds): ");
    race.readIntimes();

    double timeOne = race.getTimeOne();
    double timeTwo = race.getTimeTwo();
    double timeThree = race.getTimeThree();
```

This is what it looks like:

Enter the race times (in seconds): 
294 37 100

So the goal was to assign variables in the race class while I am outside that class and method. You need getter methods, and the setter method requires me to use "this." in front of the variable to allow you to use it as an instance variable.